# Still can't use usb in virtualbox after extension install in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, usb, virtualbox

I've downloaded the latest virtualbox 4.3 for ubuntu 13.04. And I've downloaded the latest version of the extension pack for this version, intended to enable the use of usb on a guest operating system. My guest OS is Windows XP. When I go to settings to install/pickup a usb device before opening XP, virtual box doesn't pickup any usb device, doesn't matter which port I use. What can I do further? Before version 4.3, I had 4.2. I completely removed it and started over. Then I downloaded the latest version 4.3 and the extension pack in the hope that it would resolve my previous usb issue, but with no success. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use USB you need to add your user to the vbox group.

You can do it from the command line:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

You don't need the extension pack to be able to use USB, it's only needed to install USB2 support.